My Molecular add-on does not work. What do I do to fix this?
I am a newbie in Blender, and I recently encountered an issue while following a particles tutorial. I couldn't find a solution to the issue I am having anywhere.
This is my screenshot, and there are a couple of things I am having issues with.


I can't press any of the buttons that I marked.
Even though I activated the self-collision, it's still the same as when I hadn't pressed it.
My playback is super slow, even though the rendering FPS is set to 24. After playing the whole thing, it is still slow.

I restarted my computer and Blender, and reinstalled the file in various ways from their GitHub site, but I still can't find a fix for this. Please help me out! ;(

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

"normally" this site doesn't support support for external add-ons. More information regarding molecular and newer versions here: https://blenderartists.org/t/molecular-for-blender-3-0-4-1/1285205/58 And that site is less restrictive than this site. You can essentially ask anything ;)

Hey everyone, thanks tremendously for your comments. Noted on the given link. I will take a look.
